# Something wrong with my code. It doesn't print out the even characters in my string

Tags: c, string, character, cs50

I managed to write a code, but it isn't giving me the desired output. I've tried running it via the debugger of cs50, but it shows my variable `i` to be the value `4198496`. I don't understand why, since I declared `i` to be 0. Can someone point me out why it isn't printing out the even characters?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    string input = get_string("Say something: ");
    int n = strlen(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
    
        if (input[i] % 2 == 0)
    
        printf("%c", input[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ano Show the input and the expected output.

Comment: Note that cs50 has a `string` type - an alias for `char*`. I have removed the offending (and confusing) C++ tag.

Comment: @ano "*it shows my variable `i` to be the value 4198496*" The posted code nowhere prints the `i` value, so it's not clear where that `4198496` comes from.

Comment: Sorry I'm new. I thought it was the same thing. I'm sorry if I offended c++ programmers

Comment: @ano The question should be closed because it does not make a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if the character is even, not its index, as you should (IIAC):

```
if (i % 2 == 0) { 
    printf("%c", input[i]);
}
```